# STM32G4x1 ADC Interrupt/flag when a certain value is encountered?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, adc

I am brand new with the STM32 and MCU in general. I am reading from an ADC on a continuous mode with the DMA access to memory. I would like to have some sort of "flag" for when a certain ADC value is encountered. The way that I can think of is when a new conversion is finished, interrupt the main cycle and do a manual comparison. Is there a way to do this without using cycles within the main function? Thank you!

Comment: Check your Datasheedt if your ADC supports the Analog Watchdog feature. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Did you consider to use the ADC interrupt and to check the result in the ISR?

Comment: @A.R.C. you're right, that will solve my issue. My MCU seems to have this, so I'll take a look at implementing it. Thanks a lot!